# Existence of totally ordered ring with zero divisors

Tags: ring-theory, order-theory

Does there exist a totally ordered ring with zero divisors? I can't think of an example right now.

Comment: Hint: products, lexicographic order.

Comment: If the order need not be compatible with the ring operations, no problem. If sum and product of two positive elements shall be positive again, then no.

Comment: @Daniel: Your comment might be misunderstood. So let me recall that the usual definition of a totally ordered ring is a ring whose underlying set is totally ordered via some relation $\leq$ such that $x \leq y \Rightarrow x+z \leq y+z$ and $x \leq y, 0 \leq z \Rightarrow xz \leq yz, zx \leq zy$. This *is* a compatibility condition, but it doesn't imply that $x,y > 0 \Rightarrow xy > 0$ (see my hint).

Comment: Thanks @Martin for giving the usual definition, wasn't sure what that was.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I am trying to follow your hint, without success. In $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, I take it that "lexicographic order" means $(a,b)\le(a',b')$ iff $a<a'$ or $a=a'$ and $b\le b'$. Then $(1,-5)$ and $(0,1)$ are both $\ge0$, but their product $(0,-5)$ is not, so the compatibility condition is not satisfied. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: For the counterexample to work, I think you need to define $(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',ab'+b'a)$, in other words, the ring is $\mathbb{Z}[t]/t^2$, not $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L. Fuchs, Partially Ordered Algebraic Systems. Pergamon Press, 1963

Chapt VIII, $\S 3$ "O-rings with divisors of zero".

Comment: But what about the Theorem 18.3 from "Abstract Algebra:An Inquiry Based Approach" by J.K.Hodge: An Ordered ring contains no zero divisors?

Comment: @ Victor M Sorry, I have not an access to this book.

Answer (score 7):

Too long for a comment.

It looks like there are two conflicting definitions of an ordered ring.
The first one was given by @martin-brandenburg in his comment and it is also used by L. Fuchs in his book.

The second one is proposed by J.K. Hodge in his book *Abstract Algebra: An Inquiry Based Approach* and it goes like this:

An *ordered ring* is a commutative ring $R$ containing a subset $P$ such that:

1. $P$ is not empty;
2. if $a \in P$ and $b \in P$, then $a + b \in P$ and $ab \in P$; and
3. for any $a \in R$, exactly one of following conditions holds: $a \in P$, $a = 0$, or $− a \in P$.

Let me reproduce the short proof of Theorem 18.3 pointed out by @victor-m.

**Theorem 18.3**. An ordered ring contains no zero divisors.

**Proof**. Suppose $R$ is an ordered ring, and let $a, b \in R$ with both $a$ and $b$ nonzero. If $a, b > 0$, then $ab > 0$ and so $ab \not= 0$. Suppose one of $a$ or $b$ is positive and the other negative. Without loss of generality, assume $a > 0$ and $b < 0$. Then $−b > 0$ and so $(a)(−b) > 0$. Thus, $−(ab) > 0$, which means that $ab \not= 0$. The final case is when $−a > 0$ and $−b > 0$. Then $ab = (−a)(−b) > 0$, and so $ab \not= 0$.

In conclusion, the answer depends on the definition of an ordered ring.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the definition used in Fuchs, *Partially Ordered Algebraic Systems*, take the set of integer numbers with the usual order relation and the usual addition, and define the multiplication to be trivial, so that every product be $0$.  Rings with trivial multiplication are one of the examples of ordered rings given in Fuchs's book.